# How can I create a new expression for use with Thymeleaf and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Anyone know how to extend an expressions in thymeleaf? (I need a "variety" function in thymeleaf).
Cloning a "Numbers" expression works, but...
When I make my own expression, I have error:

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

```
  [Request processing failed;
   nested exception is   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: 
   Exception evaluating SpringEL expression:
   "Variety.Variety(review.usefulScore, 'osoba', 'osoby', 'osób')"
   (static:/cms/fragments/reviews:49)] with root cause
   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
   EL1011E:(pos 8): Method call: 
  Attempted to call method  Variety(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) on null context object
```

Any suggestions?

Edit (my code):
    package org.springframework.expression;

```
import org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext;

public abstract class Variety extends StandardEvaluationContext {

    private boolean in_array(int needle, int[] haystack) {

        for(int i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
            if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String Variety(int number, String varietyFor1, String varietyFor234,  String varietyForOthers) {
        if(number == 1)
            return varietyFor1;
        if(number % 100 >= 10 && number % 100 <= 20)
            return varietyForOthers;
        if(in_array(number%10, new int[] {2,3,4}))
            return varietyFor234;
        return varietyForOthers;
    }
}
```

Edit (forgot, like allways):
I would like to use it like: ${utils.Variety(...)}

Comment: Care to show what you have done already?

Comment: package org.springframework.expression;
public abstract class Variety extends StandardEvaluationContext {
private boolean in_array(int needle, int[] haystack) {
for(int i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
return false;
}
public String Variety(int number, String varietyFor1, String varietyFor234,  String varietyForOthers) {
if(number == 1) return varietyFor1;
if(number % 100 >= 10 && number % 100 <= 20) return varietyForOthers;
if(in_array(number%10, new int[] {2,3,4})) return varietyFor234;
return varietyForOthers;
}
}

Comment: Sorry for that:) but it is my code

Comment: You might have better luck editing the question to include your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following exception shows that there is no `Variety` object on the context.

```
Attempted to call method  Variety(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) on null context object
```

The expression object must be added via a dialect. If you have added the dialect to your template engine, you will be able to use `#utils.variety(...)`.

```
public class UtilsDialect implements IExpressionEnhancingDialect {

    public static final String UTILS_EXPRESSION_OBJECT_NAME = "utils";

    private final Variety utils;

    public UtilsDialect (final Variety utils){
        this.utils = utils;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalExpressionObjects(final IProcessingContext processingContext) {
        final Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<>();
        objects.put(UTILS_EXPRESSION_OBJECT_NAME, variety);
        return objects;
    }
}
```

Also make sure you write your methods in mixed case:

```
public abstract class Variety extends StandardEvaluationContext {

    private boolean inArray(...){
        ...
    }

    public String variety(...){
        ...      
    }
}
```