# using thymeleaf +spring to create custom tags (just like JSP)

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to use Thymeleaf to create custom tags, just like in JSP.
The tag I have now is:

```
<select th:include="fragments/combobox :: combobox_beans (beans=${@accountService.getAccounts()}, innerHTML='id,description,currency', separator=' - ', dumbHtmlName='List of accounts', name='sender' )" th:remove="tag"></select>
```

The purpose is just defining the beans list, the properties of the bean to show on screen, the separator between them, the default value when shown as a native template, and the property name of the original bean we are processing here.

combobox.html:

```
<div th:fragment="combobox_beans (beans, innerHTML, separator, dumbHtmlName, name)">
<select th:field="*{__${name}__}" class="combobox form-control" required="required">
    <option th:each="obj : ${beans}" th:with="valueAsString=${#strings.replace( 'obj.' + innerHTML, ',', '+''  __${separator}__ ''+ obj.')}"
        th:value="${obj}" th:text="${valueAsString}" >            
        <p th:text="${dumbHtmlName}" th:remove="tag"></p>
    </option>
</select>
```

I need the text of the option tag to be based on the properties set in innerHTML property (**innerHTML='id,description,devise'**) of the fragment.
I end up having an option with this text:

```
<option value="...">obj.id+' - '+ obj.description+' - '+ obj.currency</option>
```

instead of the desired result

```
<option value="...">2 - primary - USD</option>
```

I know this is due to the usage of *Strings* library which results in a string.
Is there a way Thymeleaf can re-evaluate this string to be understood as an object again?

Maybe using strings library is just so wrong in this situation... Maybe I need to use a *th:each* to process the each bean as an object and read its properties, but yet again, how to only get the properties specified in innerHtml ?

Anyone has a solution or work-around for this ?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is a way to do what you want in Thymeleaf/Spring expression alone, it most certainly very complicated and long winded, plus it would probably be a pain to read.

The easier way to do it would be add a custom utility object to the expression context. Very little code is needed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21283022/1177013) shows it.

Then you need to add you new dialect as additional dialect to the template engine in your Spring xml config. Assuming you have a fairly standard Spring config, it should be similar to this.

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
  <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
  <property name="additionalDialects">
    <set>
      <bean class="mypackage.MyUtilityDialect" />
    </set>
  </property>
</bean>
```

**Now for the utility object**

What you want is to get the properties from objects by name, and combine their values with a separator. It seems that the list of property names can be of any size. For accessing properties by name, the most convenient thing is to use a library like the [Apache beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

Your custom utility object could the look something like this using the Java 8 streams library, lambdas and Beanutils:

```
public class MyUtil {

  public String joinProperties(Object obj, List<String> props, String separator){
    return props.stream()
          .map(p -> PropertyUtils.getProperty(obj,p).toString())
          .collect(Collectors.joining(separator))
  }
}
```

Then when you add you dialect to SpringTemplateEngine you can call your utility:

```
th:with="valueAsString=${#myutils.joinProperties(obj,properties,separator)}"
```

I have replaced you `innerHTML` parameter with `properties` which is a `List<String>`, because it makes more sense. It is essentially a list of property names, and Spring EL supports inline lists.

Your calling tag should then look like this.

```
<select th:include="fragments/combobox :: combobox_beans (beans=${@accountService.getAccounts()}, properties=${ {'id','description','currency'} }, separator=' - ', dumbHtmlName='List of accounts', name='sender' )" th:remove="tag"></select>
```

Comment: That worked !!! A note for other users: you do not have to implement any processors or any of the methods from IExpressionEnhancingDialect. Just fill them with Collections.EMPTY_MAP and Collections.emptySet(). You just need to implement the getPrefix and getAdditionalExpressionObjects() as @irpbc referred in his linked answer.